# is it possible to implement listview inside childview of expandable listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am developing application for school.I have to implement time table for lecture in expandable listview.how to make listview as childview of expandable listview?

Answer (score 0):

it will technically compile but you won't be able to scroll one of them and it's bad practice to do so ,
you might want to consider TableView for your app